# Reset Identity Seed ('DBCC CHECKIDENT ... RESEED' is not working)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dbcc

For my unit tests I have an automated process which builds a copy of a DB, table by table. I first of all run a `SELECT INTO` and add the primary key and any indices.

Some of the tables I copy with data, and for those *without* data I wish to reset the identity seed.

To achieve this I have the following `T-SQL` statement:

```
EXEC('TRUNCATE TABLE [' + @TableName + '];')
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.identity_columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@TableName) AND last_value IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    EXEC('DBCC CHECKIDENT (' + @TableName + ', reseed, 1)')
END
```

The query runs without any reported problems but when I inspect the table in design view the *Identity Seed* value is never reset.

Can anyone please tell me why the Identity Seed is not being reset, or what else I need to do?

**UPDATE:**
As per some comments I have modified the *sys.identity_columns* to the following:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.identity_columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@TableName))
```

When run, this returns the following message:

> Checking identity information: current identity value '1'.
>   DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.

Which looks promising. However, if I then refresh the table (in the Object Explorer) and look at it in the design view, the Identity Seed is unchanged, *i.e.* not 1 (or 0) but 135.

Comment: What about the squares around the table, as you did in the truncate?

Comment: Also confirm that it is in fact getting to that EXEC.  Some debug comments or alerts.

Comment: Just tried it, but it makes no difference.

Comment: As far as *does it reach the EXEC?* I've tried running it with a return statement of `SELECT 1` (if there is an identity column) otherwise `SELECT 0`, and this returns the results for various tables (with and without identity columns) as I'd expect.

Comment: `TRUNCATE TABLE` already resets the identity to its current seed value. So your `last_value IS NOT NULL` condition will not match and the `CHECKIDENT` will never happen (but then, it shouldn't even be necessary...)

Comment: On a side note, if you want the next row entered to be 1, then you actually need to use the command `DBCC CHECKIDENT (' + @TableName + ', RESEED, 0)`

Comment: If you just truncated, why do you need to reseed?  [Truncate table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177570.aspx) already resets identities.

Comment: A reseed will not change the identity *specification* for the table, which is always a record of what was specified when the table was created - so if it was defined as `IDENTITY(5,1)` then you'll always see the seed as `5`. You *can* do a reseed to any value and that new value will be respected but in order for that to work against a *truncated* table you'll need to take out your `last_value is not null` check to allow the `reseed` to always happen.

Comment: I Agree with BaconBits.  That is why I think it is permissions.  More than likely the truncate is not even working.

Comment: @BaconBits - I've tried simply TRUNCATEing the table, but the Identity Seed remains unchanged.

Comment: As I tried to say in my previous comment, but maybe not clearly enough - looking in design view tells you **nothing** about what value will be used for the next insert. It tells you what the original specification was. Have you tried actually *inserting* a row after this and seeing what value gets generated?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - Aha! Sorry, I missed that in a sudden barrage of comments. You're absolutely right. Design view says 135 but an INSERT command reveals an ID of 1. Why don't you post as a suggested answer?

Comment: Just curious, why do you use `EXEC`? Can't you just call `DBCC CHECKIDENT (@TableName, RESEED, 1);` without using `EXEC`? In my case, without using `EXEC`, it does reset the number. Maybe I missed something in my code, but it worked without `EXEC`

Answer (score 3):

Ran into a similar problem assigning the identity key (in my case to a larger value). In my case I found that if I ran DBCC CHECKIDENT (TableName) after running the DBCHECKIDENT RESEED it would then fully "refresh" itself into the new value. Otherwise it will get stuck on an older value. I don't know why, but it worked in my case (and may be useful to someone else.)

Comment: this worked for me only in one instance. honestly this whole reseeding-problem looks like a bug in MS SQL.
Stay away from reseeding as much as possible

Comment: This actually works for me. Not sure if it is one instance or not. I hope it works all the time. Thanks Jeff...!

Comment: for me, I was running DBCC CHECKIDENT (TableName) after running the reseed and was having the problem. Finally I tried inserting a record immediately after reseed and then it worked. Odd.

Comment: I had the same problem as @EilertHjelmeseth I needed to insert a record immediately after reseed and not check the DBCC CHECKIDENT or else it would get stuck